# UIPickerViewDelegate in Swift

Tags: swift, function, methods, protocols

I am following a tutorial on lynda on basic Swift with Xcode. Now we have a code that uses Picker view with custom data. The idea is pretty simple, add data to that spinning wheel but I have difficulty reading methods in this protocol. There is this one - pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:

I wonder how it gets a row value. By spinning wheel with finger or?? A code for this method goes like this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return moodArray[row]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picker view is asking its delegate a question. "For the row and column(component) at index x what should my title be? Send me a String to let me know"

It's up to you to return a string from your moods array. Happy, Sad, Truculent , Confused . It's up to you.

Delegate methods are used so that to create a UI component there is no need to subclass objects. Literally you delegate work to an outside contractor.

Comment: I think I get it now. I have one more, smaller question. Somewhere I see Delegate Protocol, somewhere Protocol. Are that terms the same thing? Or there is some big diference?

Comment: same thing more or less. A protocol is a bunch of methods which your object should implement when it adopts a protocol. Sometimes methods are optional , sometimes not. A delegate protocol is just an extra semantic explanation of why the protocol exists.

Comment: Thanks. And one more question. This syntax is unfamiliar with me: titleForRow row: Int, why is there 2 names before type?

Comment: Check `Function Parameter Names` (p274?) in the Swift book . First one is external name, second one is internal to the function. In this case, it comes from the automatic Obj-C conversion.